# added custom primary key, but still giving error for old default id column in the table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

i have two relations for example example1 and example2
and example1 has_one example2
example2 belongs_to example1

```
example1
 phone_number primary key
example2
 phone_number foreign key
```

when i do this

```
Example1.create!({phone_number:"1231231231"})
```

and

```
u = User.find_by_phone_number("1231231231")
u.example2 = Example2.new(attributes)
```

it gives me error saying example1_id undefined column
and i have deleted activerecords default id columns to add my own primary key

can anyone please help me here 
i think i am missing some trick for models association.
thanks.!!

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to ignore Rails defaults. How do your has_many and belongs_to definitions look in the models? (You would have to define the column names you decided to use there)

Comment: in example1 has_one example2 and in example2 belongs_to example1

Comment: So you changed the id column name and didn't give Rails the info what the columns name is. How are those columns named? You can use something like: `belongs_to :example_one, :foreign_key => "some_other_id_than_expected"`

Comment: so should that be in example1 or example2 becos my foreign key is in example2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
belongs_to :example_1, :foreign_key => "phone_number"
```

Comment: i have given that in migration, do we still need this.
in migration i am doing alter table add foreign key to that column